# Android studio not detecting device

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, debugging, android-studio

I have recently installed android studio in my PC(Windows 8) and I have tried connecting my phone to test an app. But it is not displaying the phone in the device selector. The PC is detecting the phone and the USB debugging is turned on. Even eclipse is detecting the device. Android studio version 0.8.2. I have tried connecting the phone in a friends laptop(Windows 7) and same issue. It is showing in eclipse but not in android studio.

Comment: Do you have updated sdk for android studio.

Comment: Updated SDK to latest version. Yes..

Answer (score 1):

i think adb.exe is responsible for choosing device and for debugging. so pls check if adb exists in sdk path. if your eclipse android sdk path is working , pls set same sdk path for android studio too. it may help you. [adb link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

Answer (score 0):

You try this:
[image]

To restart adb:

1. power off your phone
2. connect the USB cable
3. On your phone
4. Run `adb devices`
5. You should see the attached device now